# Adding new row in a table on key press adds extra line in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom-events

I have a table with three columns. Each row, first and third columns are input fields and the second column in each row is a content editable div.

When a user is on  content editable div and he presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then it should add a new row just below it and`focus should be shifted from the current content editable div to the content editable div of the new row.

The problem is on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press, with the addition of new row inside a table it also adds up extra line in the current content editable.

Here is plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/QxZC4bVgWOHJ65pM9F38?p=preview

Comment: `preventDefault` or `return false` at the end of the keydown function doesn't help?

Answer (score 0):

The onKeyDown function in your app.js file should be

```
  $scope.onKeyDown = function($event, index) {
    if ($event.keyCode == ENTER_KEY){
      $event.preventDefault();
      nextIndex = index + 1
      $scope.list.splice(nextIndex, 0, initNewRow())
      setfocusOnNewRow(nextIndex)
    }
  }
```

Note the $event.preventDefault(); line.